# Android SQL Filterable Query the returns results like "startswith"

Tags: android, sql, filter, android-edittext, simplecursoradapter

The following code is what I am using for a edit text in a simple_list_item_1 listview. However, when typing a single character, the filter will return everthing, but typing a second character will return everything with that "pattern".

What I am trying to acheive is something like, "startswith" so that when a single character is typed into the edittext, all entries are filtered for that character. Example, If I type the letter A (upper or lower case) I should see all entries that start with the letter A. And if the second character. For example AB is typed in, all entries should filter in accordance with AB. Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this?

```
 public Cursor getFlavorsList (CharSequence constraint)  {
  SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
  queryBuilder.setTables(
    DATABASE_TABLE2
  );

  String asColumnsToReturn[] = { 
        KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME
  };

  if (constraint == null  ||  constraint.length () == 0)  {
    //  Return the full list
    return queryBuilder.query(mDB, asColumnsToReturn, null, null,
            null, null, DATABASE_TABLE2);
  }  else  {
  String value = "%"+constraint.toString()+"%";

  return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, asColumnsToReturn, "KEY_NAME like ? ",   new  String[]{value}, null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that one got me for a hour or two but this is the way to get the results you are looking for. This will filter on the first character entered and not return the pattern as you say. For example, type in A and only the "A" list will show up. Type in B and only the "B" list will show up. Also this is not case sensitive.

The difference is drop the "%" in front of the constraint.

```
 public Cursor getflavorlist (CharSequence constraint)  {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(
            DATABASE_TABLE2
    );

    String asColumnsToReturn[] = {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME};

    if (constraint == null  ||  constraint.length () == 0)  {
        //  Return the full list
        return queryBuilder.query(mDb, asColumnsToReturn, null, null,
                null, null, KEY_NAME);
    }  else  {
        String value = ""+constraint.toString()+"%";

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, asColumnsToReturn, "name like ? ", new String[]{value}, null, null, null);
    }
}
```